# List all customers via stripe API

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get a list of all the customers in my stripe account but am limited by pagination, wanted to know what the most pythonic way to do this.

```
customers = []
results = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)
print len(results.data)
for c in results:
    customers.append(c)
results = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100, starting_after=results.data[-1].id)
for c in results:
    customers.append(c)
```

This lists the first 200, but then how do I do this if I have say 300, 500, etc customers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stripe's Python library has an "auto-pagination" feature:

```
customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)
for customer in customers.auto_paging_iter():
    # Do something with customer
```

The `auto_paging_iter` method will iterate over every customer, firing new requests as needed in the background until every customer has been retrieved.

The auto-pagination feature is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=python).

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for.